# Получить статус link в Mikrotik через api в php

Tags: php, api, mikrotik

Узнать статус в интерфейсе ethernet  определенного порта. Через терминал в Mikrotik это возможно через команду interface ethernet monitor ether1, терминал выведет общию информацию на порту. Необходимо вытащить только satatus, который может быть в состоянии link-on, link-off, вывести через api в php.

Разные статусы в самом интерфейсе winbox я могу вытащить, а вот этот не получается

Comment: Старайтесь писать вопросы более развернуто и с примерами кода, который делали вы, а также ошибки которые происходят в ходе, здесь телепаты отсутствуют.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить необходимые данные, нужно отправить следующий запрос:

```
/interface/ethernet/monitor
=.id=*1
=once=
```

При этом `*1` это ID интерфейса. Его можно получить при помощи следующего запроса:

```
/interface/ethernet/print
=.proplist=.id
?name=ether1
```